# angle of twist of gear relative to another

Tags: mechanical-engineering

why we need to consider 2 moment caused by the 85Nm in this question ? The question ask for the determine the angle of twist of gear A relative to D .

Why shouldnt the angle of twist = **(85)(0.4)** / (      (0.5pi)( 0.015^4- 0.01^4)(75)(10^9)  )  + (85)(0.25) / (0.5pi)(0.02^4)(75)(10^9) only ? [image: c]

Answer (score 0):

I almost had this in a comment but it might as well be an answer.

There should indeed be that 2 there.  You are summing the twist in each of the bars and adding them together.  Both the hollow sections attached to gears have the same torque and sizes, so they will have the same value.  Instead of writing out the twist for that bar separately they just multiply the first term by 2 since it will just be that again.

Comment: Why are they all positive ? We could see that the direction of torque are different , right ?

Comment: So if the torques are different; they will obviously make it twist more.  If the torque was the same direction I don't think the question would make sense; the bar wouldn't even want to twist.  One of the torques is more of a reaction torque resisting the twist at the end.  The result is that each bar has the same torque acting to twist it.

Comment: why  If the torque was the same direction ; the bar wouldn't even want to twist ????@JMac

Comment: @kelvinmacks What would cause it to twist?  There would be nothing stopping it from just spinning more.  This situation is like a cantilever beam for moments.  In a cantilever beam, one side has a force applied while the other side resists this force, causing bending.  In this scenario, one side is applying a rotational motion, the other side is resisting that; which give you the twist.  If the other side didn't resist; it wouldn't be twisting; it would just be spinning freely.

Comment: It might be a bit clearer if you understand what the gear at D is doing.  In real life that gear would be connected to another gear (lets call it gear E), which is getting torque applied to it from gear D.  The torque we see on gear D is actually a reaction to the force on gear E.  It's the "equal and opposite reaction" which causes it to act opposite of the direction that the applied moment to the shaft.

Comment: yes , we can notice that all of the T in the case above have same sign . You also pointed that if torque was the same direction ; the bar wouldn't even want to twist , so , how can the AB , BC and CD twist , since the torque are of the same direction ?

Comment: It twists because each of those sections has same same positive torque relative to the end at point D; where the torque is balanced.  Here's a picture showing how it's similar to a cantilever beam (which you should be familiar with) http://i.imgur.com/wtJscle.png

Comment: do you mean one end is fixed , while the another 3 parts will undergo torque which is opposite to the reactive end ?

Comment: It's not exactly "fixed" per-se; it definitely can still move.  The whole thing is rotating.  In reality there would be more gears coupled to each of those gears.  Gear D would be transmitting power to a gear coupled with it(calling it "gear E" again).  That gear would have a reaction that is opposite what it applied (basic physics; equal but opposite reaction).